# Save config file multiple user getting an error The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a web api which save the some information inside web.config file on every request .
below is the code. when multiple request hit application I am getting an error  intermittently  'The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process'

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(string.Empty);
ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(_appSettings);
 -- modify config section and then save
config.Save();
```

Comment: Hi, thats a very unusual thing to do. But of course it doesn't work because the second request tries to access the file for write while the first is currently writing. This is possible to do if you handle it by yourself but still the chance is very high that you end up with an invalid file. Why not using a database?

Comment: Yeah, don't do that! What are you storing in the config that needs to be changed for every request?

Comment: its password we are doing protecting & unprotecting on  every request. like below if (section != null && !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                
                // Get the name of the default provider
                var pcs = (ProtectedConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("configProtectedData");
                var provider = pcs.DefaultProvider;

                // Apply the provider to the section and save
                section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
                config.Save();

            }